# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves $\ x = 6+y^2, x=0, y=1$, and $\ y = 3 $ about the x-axis.

Tags: calculus, volume

At first, I kept the problem in terms y and used 1 and 3 as the bounds. I also tried putting it in terms of x and found that the second bound was 6 and the first bound was given which was 0. I'm confused about how to determine the bounds. How does the given information, $\ x=6+y^2, x=0, y=1,$ and $\ y=3$ , help us solve the problem?

Comment: In your title you say $y = y^2 + 6$. That gives you a number; Which one do you want to be $x$?

Comment: It's supposed to be x=6+y^2

Comment: Do you know either the shell or the disc method?

Comment: Yes I do. For this problem I was told to use the disc method because the function is being rotated about the x-axis.

Comment: Don't memorize it that way; the shell method is for integrating perpendicular to the independent variable, whereas the disc is for things parallel to the independent variable.

Comment: Do you know how to set the integral up for this problem? I'm not sure how to set it up using the washer method. I tried the disc method but I got the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating with respect to $y$ and using 1 and 3 as your bounds makes a lot of sense.

Sketch the region if you are having trouble finding your bounds.  Here is my sketch of your region.

[image]

If you wanted to integrate with respect to x, you would need to break this into two integrals.  One from 0 to 7 and one from 7 to 15.

Comment: Would you use the washer method then to solve this problem? I'm not sure how to set the integral up. I tried using the disc method because I'm not sure the outer and inner radii.

Comment: If I am integrating with respect to y, and rotating about the x-axis that would be shells.